# getClassLoader().getResource("filename").getFile() includes the JAR File Name in file path

Tags: java, maven, classloader, file-handling

I'm updating a system for additional requirements by the client. It is an old system which runs on java 1.4.2 and is compiled using maven and jdk 1.5.0_11.

One part of the system is loading of property file. The syntax used is:

```
String fileName = "MyClass".class.getClassLoader().getResource("MyFile.txt").getFile();
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document document = builder.build(fileName);
```

I did not change anything on that code. However, when I deployed the jar file in Linux, it creates an incorrect file path. Currently, MyFile.txt is located inside the same folder as the compiled jar, and the code above from Old JAR get the correct file path. However, with the new compiled jar file, the generated file path of MyFile.txt included the name of the Jar in the file path. Please see below for more explanation.

Assuming that compiled Jar is CompiledJarv01.jar and is deployed in /Apps/myJar folder (MyFile.txt is inside also), the full file path of the MyFile.txt is

Old JAR File: /Apps/myJar/MyFile.txt

New JAR File: /Apps/myJar/CompiledJarv01.jar!/MyFile.txt

I am not sure why the Jar file name was included in MyFile.txt file path. This causes FileNotFoundException when running the application.

Comment: I doubt that the first one is actually contained within the Jar, but was a file which was within the classpath

Comment: If your resource is within a jar file, then you cannot get a filename for it. You need to load via an InputStream.

Comment: I did not change any File Handling code inside the application. I decompiled the old jar file and I found out that it uses the same syntax. However, they bahave differently. I suspect it has something to do with the java versions I used in compiling though I am realy not sure.

Comment: If you want to load a file that is sitting next to the jar file using the classloader mechanism you have now (as opposed to just reading it from the file system), then you need to include that directory on the class path (and before the jar itself).

Comment: I found out that the difference with the two JAR files is that the NEW one contains all the file inside the JAR file. The OLD one does not have those files inside it. Any idea how this happen or how to correct it? Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Thilo for your help. IO found out that the cause of my issue are the config files that is packaged in JAR file during compilation. These files are under src/main/resources/config folder. Though it was declared in classpath and maven config to exclude this config folder, it was still included in Java build path. I went to Project Properties>>Java Build Path>>Source and I delete the src/main/resources/config on the build path.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like:

```
File resource = new File("MyClass".class.getClassLoader().getResource("MyFile.txt").getFile());
String fileName = resource.getName();
File compiledJar = resource.getParentFile();
File newResource = new File(compiledJar.getParentFile(), filename);
System.out.println("The file you want (Hope so, I got no IDE): " + newResoruce.toString());
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. However, I can't change the original code. I am checking what is wrong with the classpath and maven settings to resove the issue. Thanks